# how to automate documentation creation using doxygen?

Tags: c++, tcl, doxygen

I have a c++ library .And I have generated its documentation using doxygen. And I am using tcl  application over this c++ library. So I want to automatically create documentation for the tcl layer. Is there any doxygen tag that will do my job?  reply its urgent....

Answer (score 1):

A good article here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/27011
(Short answer from that page: as long as you have at least doxygen 1.7.5, it works. You might need to define additional commands that do substitutions inside them in order to pick up all relevant declarations.)